# firebase functions showing error cannot read property previous of undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I had implemented firebase functions in my app and previously it was working fine but now it is showing error **Cannot read property 'previous' of undefined**

**Error Logs of function**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'previous' of undefined
at exports.LoveNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:223:16)
at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:109:23)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:139:20)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:730:24
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Answer (score 2):

The signature of Cloud Functions triggers has changed. You seem to be using beta, but are deploying to the latest version. See the [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff) for complete instructions.

From there:

> Before (<= v0.9.1)
>
> ```
> exports.dbWrite = functions.database.ref('/path').onWrite((event) => {
>   const beforeData = event.data.previous.val(); // data before the write
>   const afterData = event.data.val(); // data after the write
> });
> ```
>
> Now (>= v1.0.0)
>
> ```
> exports.dbWrite = functions.database.ref('/path').onWrite((change, context) => {
>   const beforeData = change.before.val(); // data before the write
>   const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write
> });
> ```

So your code should look something like this:

```
exports.LoveNotification = functions.database.ref("/Member/{pushId}").onWrite((change, context) => {

 if (change.before.exists()) {
    return;
 } else {
    var eventLove = change.after.data.val();
    var author =eventLove.fullname;
    var title = eventLove.course;
    var key = eventLove.key;

    const payload = {
        "data": {
                    "post_id": key
                  },
        notification: {
            title: author +'Joined the app',
            body: `Course `+title,
            sound: "default",
            icon: "ic_launcher",

        }
    };

    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24 //24 hours
    };
    console.log('Sending notifications');
    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("Member", payload, options);

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please help me with the updated version as i had tried some minor changes but that didn't worked out. .Can you please post the updated code for my code.I tried but messed up.

Comment: I added a quick version. But if you're new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.