# Cannot read property 'previous' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions

Functions in firebase throws me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'previous' of undefined
at exports.sendNotifications.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/srv/index.js:5:19)
at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
at /worker/worker.js:825:24
at <anonymous>
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

And my code is this:

```
exports.sendNotifications=functions.database.ref('/notifications/{notificationId}').onWrite((event)=>{
if(event.data.previous.val()){
  return;
}
if(!event.data.exists()){
  return;
}
})
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Because event.data is undefined. Probably because you are fetching a notification that does not exist.

Comment: You seem to be using an old tutorial or something. The signature of Cloud Functions has changed (quite some time ago). For info on how to update, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51782831/firebase-functions-showing-error-cannot-read-property-previous-of-undefined (which is the first question that pops up when I [search for the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-functions%5D+Cannot+read+property+%27previous%27+of+undefined)).

Answer (score 0):

That often means that `event` does not have property `data` all the time. So you need to check first:

```
if('data' in event && event.data.previous.val()){
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because there is no data inside event so check that first. One of the ways is:

```
exports.sendNotifications=functions.database.ref('/notifications/{notificationId}').onWrite((event)=>{
if(!event.data){
  return;
}
if(event.data.previous.val()){
  return;
}
if(!event.data.exists()){
  return;
}
})
```